# Moving a Chatrooom to another site

Tags: support, chat, se-sites

I am not exactly sure where I should be posing this question, but I suppose I'll try here. I created a chatroom, called "Russell's On Denoting," which I intended for the philosophy stackexchange. But for some strange reason it created it in the math stackexchange chatroom. Is there is way of moving it?

Comment: Meta.SE: [Chat room owner should be able to change the room's associated SE site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268559) and [How can I change the related site for a chatroom after the room is created?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268517)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moderators of the host site can change the host of a chatroom if they have an account on the intended new host site. I'm going to try that out in a few minutes (I need to create an account on the philosophy site first).

The host of your chat room has been changed now.